# UnimplementedError with Neural Network Using Linear Regression and Tensorflow2

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, nlp, word-embedding

I'm just working through my own sandbox project wanting to try and implement NLP but with a linear regression as an outcome. As reference, the dataset I am working with comes [Kaggle wine-reviews](https://www.kaggle.com/zynicide/wine-reviews) which has the wine reviews and a corresponding score of 1 through 100 hence why I'm using linear regression instead of classification.

But I am getting an error message and I'm not sure if it's a result of a data type or dimensionality problem, and I'm not sue why or how to resolve it.

I'll provide the code bellow, and  some intermediate outcomes displaying the dimensions of some of the objects as I'm assuming that that might be useful in solving this.

```
df = pd.read_csv('winemag-data_first150k.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
y = df['points'].astype(int)
X = df['description'].astype(str)

# split up the data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)

MAX_VOCAB_SIZE = 35000
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_VOCAB_SIZE)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)
sequences_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
sequences_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)

word2idx = tokenizer.word_index
V = len(word2idx)
print('Found %s unique tokens.' % V)
   Found 33012 unique tokens.

data_train = pad_sequences(sequences_train)
print('Shape of data train tensor:', data_train.shape)

# get sequence length
T = data_train.shape[1]
   Shape of data train tensor: (101123, 136)

data_test = pad_sequences(sequences_test, maxlen=T)
print('Shape of data test tensor:', data_test.shape)
   Shape of data test tensor: (49807, 136)

# Create the model

# We get to choose embedding dimensionality
D = 20

# Hidden state dimensionality
M = 15



i = Input(shape=(T,))
x = Embedding(V + 1, D)(i)
x = LSTM(M, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
x = Dense(1)(x)

model = Model(i, x)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')


# learning rate scheduler
def schedule(epoch, lr):
  if epoch >= 50:
    return 0.0001
  return 0.001
 

scheduler = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(schedule)


# Train the model
r = model.fit(X, y, epochs=200, callbacks=[scheduler])
```

And then I get the error message along with a warning about dimensionality:

```
Epoch 1/200
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 136) for input Tensor("input_10:0", shape=(None, 136), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1).
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 136) for input Tensor("input_10:0", shape=(None, 136), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1).
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-0f68916ec23b> in <module>
     13 
     14 # Train the model
---> 15 r = model.fit(X, y, epochs=200, callbacks=[scheduler])

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    838         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    839         # stateless function.
--> 840         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    841     else:
    842       canon_args, canon_kwds = \

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2827     with self._lock:
   2828       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 2829     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2830 
   2831   @property

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs, cancellation_manager)
   1841       `args` and `kwargs`.
   1842     """
-> 1843     return self._call_flat(
   1844         [t for t in nest.flatten((args, kwargs), expand_composites=True)
   1845          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1921         and executing_eagerly):
   1922       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
-> 1923       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
   1924           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1925     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    543       with _InterpolateFunctionError(self):
    544         if cancellation_manager is None:
--> 545           outputs = execute.execute(
    546               str(self.signature.name),
    547               num_outputs=self._num_outputs,

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57   try:
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
     [[node functional_11/Cast (defined at <ipython-input-121-0f68916ec23b>:15) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_17206]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I'm not entirely sure what needs to be changed, but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You are passing X to model.fit, which literally has string values, a neural network cannot be input string values.

Comment: Oh god, I can't believe I did that .You're right. You win. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From comments

> Passing `X` to `model.fit`, which literally has string values, a neural
> network cannot be input string values (paraphrased from Dr. Snoopy)